# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp\www\DbConnect.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

This is my php code and whenever i runs it i get that error ...database is on localhost wamp server

```
<?php
$username ="root";
$password= "";
$hostname ="localhost";
$database ="mydata";
$check="";
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$i = "SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE 1";
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($i);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($i))
{
$r[]=$row;
$check=$row["emailid"];
}
if($check==NULL)
{
$r[$num_rows]="Record is not available";
print(json_encode($r));
}
else
{
$r[$num_rows]="success";
print(json_encode($r));
}
//mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

please suggest the solution for this.

Comment: Query __must be executed__

Comment: I would recommend that you read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and/or any of the 10.000 tutorials about PHP and MySQLi that exists out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your connection

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

you have wrong sql

change this

```
$i = "SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE 1";
```

to

```
$i = "SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE your_cloumn_name = 1";
```

and you have not executed the your

add

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$i);
```

and then

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```